# Javascript ReactJs Type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render "OTHERPAGE" when a user clicks the back button ... snippet:

```
onClickBack:function(e){
    var parentId = getParentIdById(this.props.id);
    React.render(<OTHERPAGE id={parentId} />, document.getElementById('main'));
},
```

the function triggers as i expect it. 
getParentIdById returns the UUID as a string, just how I need it.
calling React.render throws an exception:

message:"element.type is not a constructor"

I dont get it... I required React on top of the page:

```
var React = require('react');
```

does anyone know what the problem could be here?

Thanks for helping

**EDIT:**

I also get this warning:

> "Warning: Only functions or strings can be mounted as React
>   components."

Doesn't really help me though...

Comment: My guess is `OTHERPAGE` isn't what you think it is. What's the output of `console.log(OTHERPAGE)`?

Comment: I think you are right... it returned "Object { }" instead of "function OTHERPAGE(config, children)" ... but why?

Comment: Max, that's outside the scope of the information you've given.

Comment: Yes @FakeRainBrigand I fear it is. I was hoping that it was some kind of common issue... I am trying to restructure using react-router

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the exact same error.

Comment: @Lee I worked around the issue by using react-router ... maybe this is what you should do aswell? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to export the OTHERPAGE from it's file:

file OTHERPAGE.react.js:

```
var OTHERPAGE = React.createClass({...});
module.exports = OTHERPAGE;
```

use the OTHERPAGE component:

```
var OTHERPAGE = require('./components/OTHERPAGE.react');
var React = require('react');

var parentId = ...;
React.render(<OTHERPAGE id={parentId} />, document.getElementById('main'));
```